# Enzyme: Value returns undefined when simulating onSubmit

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to simulate the way the form was submitted. So to summarize when the user types in the `textarea` 'field, the component must be updated, then the user presses the submit button and the component is updated again. I expect that the value filled in the textarea will be empty after the user successfully submit. But unexpectedly the returned value is `undefined`.

**CommentBox.js**

```js
import React from 'react';

class CommentBox extends React.Component {
    state = {
        comment: ''
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            comment: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <h4>Add a comment</h4>
                <textarea onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.comment} />
                <div>
                    <button>Submit Comment</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default CommentBox;
```

**CommentBox.text.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import CommentBox from 'components/CommentBox';

let wrapped;

beforeEach(() => {
    wrapped = mount(<CommentBox />);
})

afterEach(() => {
    wrapped.unmount();
})

it('when form is submitted, text area gets emptied', () => {
    wrapped.find('textarea').simulate('change', {
        target: { value: 'new comment' }
    })

    wrapped.update();
    wrapped.find('form').simulate('submit', {
        preventDefault: () => {}
    });
    wrapped.update();

    expect(wrapped.find('textarea').prop('value')).toEqual('');
})
```

I expect the output will be passed but the actual output is value returns undefined so test is failed.

Comment: handleSubmit() does not set textarea to its initial value ' ', it just cancels form submission; so test case is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything that would make the test fail... other than not including `this.setState({ comment: "" });` in the `handleSubmit` callback.

If you utilize `state`, then you have to manually reset it (or if the component unmounts, then it loses `state` automatically). React works by manipulating a virtual `DOM`. Then, you utilize `state` to manipulate the elements within this virtual `DOM`. Since you're preventing a page refresh (`e.preventDefault`) the `state` persists as intended.

**Working example** (click the `Tests` tab -- next to the `Browser` tab -- to run the test):

[image: Edit CommentBox Testing]

---

**components/CommentBox**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class CommentBox extends Component {
  state = { comment: "" };

  handleChange = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    this.setState({ comment: value });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log("submitted comment: ", this.state.comment);

    this.setState({ comment: "" });
  };

  render = () => (
    <div className="app">
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <h4>Add a comment</h4>
        <textarea
          className="uk-textarea"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.comment}
        />
        <div className="button-container">
          <button type="submit" className="uk-button uk-button-primary">
            Submit Comment
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CommentBox;
```

**components/CommentBox/__tests__/CommentBox.test.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import CommentBox from "../index";

describe("Comment Box", () => {
  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<CommentBox />);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    wrapper.unmount();
  });

  it("when form is submitted, text area gets emptied", () => {
    wrapper.find("textarea").simulate("change", {
      target: { value: "new comment" }
    });

    expect(wrapper.find("textarea").prop("value")).toEqual("new comment");

    wrapper.find("form").simulate("submit", {
      preventDefault: () => {}
    });

    expect(wrapper.find("textarea").prop("value")).toEqual("");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
handleChange = (e) => {
 if(e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey == false) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.myFormRef.submit();
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <form ref={el => this.myFormRef = el}  >
            <h4>Add a comment</h4>
            <textarea onKeyDown={this.handleChange} value={this.state.comment} 
             />
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Submit Comment</button>
            </div>
        </form>

 );
}
```

you can do like this on enter

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
import React from 'react';

class CommentBox extends React.Component {
    //adding initVal for setting initial value in textbox
    // and playing with it until the form submits
    state = {
        comment: '',
        initVal: ''
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        //on change in textfield, updating initVal with the typed text
        this.setState({
            initVal: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        //finally on submission comment is updated with entered value
        //which you may use it for further operations
        //and initVal is set back to empty '' for setting textfield value as empty 
        //field
        this.setState({
            comment: this.state.initVal
            initVal: ''
        })
        //event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <h4>Add a comment</h4>
                //changes here
                <textarea onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.initVal} />
                <div>
                    <button>Submit Comment</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default CommentBox;
```